# Azure Function - Slow to aquire singleton lock and why is it needed?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I have a function app written in C# / netcoreapp3.1 which is hosted on a consumption plan. It hosts 6 timer functions and 3 queue functions. The queue functions are performing slower than I'd like. I'd expect these functions to execute in 200-300ms on average. I do see this but only for out of every 10 messages or so. The rest take a lot longer. Here's the invocation trace for one of the queue functions:

| Timestamp | Message | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:22.255 | Executing 'PriceHandler' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'price'.', Id=FOO) | Information |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:22.255 | Executing '"PriceHandler"' (Reason='"New queue message detected on 'price'."', Id=FOO) |  |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:22.256 | Trigger Details: MessageId: BAR, DequeueCount: 3, InsertionTime: 2021-01-07T20:47:45.000+00:00 | Information |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:22.256 | Trigger Details: MessageId: "BAR", DequeueCount: "3", InsertionTime: "2021-01-07T20:47:45.000+00:00" |  |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.293 | Singleton lock acquired (yadda) |  |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.294 | Processing Message : "{ Json msg ~2k bytes }" | Information |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.298 | Start processing HTTP request "GET" https://api/123 | Information |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.298 | Sending HTTP request "GET" https://api/123 | Information |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.379 | Received HTTP response after 80.397ms - OK | Information |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.379 | End processing HTTP request after 81.4436ms - OK | Information |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.491 | Singleton lock released (yadda) |  |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.492 | Executed 'PriceHandler' (Succeeded, Id=FOO, Duration=20301ms) | Information |
| 2021-01-07 21:08:42.492 | Executed '"PriceHandler"' ("Succeeded", Id=FOO, Duration=20301ms) |  |

I noticed that for most of the invocations there is a large delay between the "Trigger Details" event and the "Singleton lock acquired". Several tens of seconds as shown above. I'm not sure why the function would need a "Singleton lock" but any ideas why the function runtime is taking so long to get it? Also, how would I disable it? I'd like multiple instances of the function to spin up on the same VM if possible and I assume that by having a "Singleton lock" it isn't going to do that.

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "00:10:00",
  "aggregator": {
    "batchSize": 1000,
    "flushTimeout": "00:00:30"
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:05:00",
      "batchSize": 15,
      "maxDequeueCount": 600,
      "newBatchThreshold": 10
    }
  },
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20,
        "excludedTypes": "Request;Trace"
      }
    }
  },
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "System": "Information"
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ]
  },
  "WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT": 2
}
```

App settings:
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION: ~3
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME: dotnet
(...And other app-specific things.)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that acquiring the singleton lock was the primary reason for the poor performance. The solution was embarrassingly simple: Remove the [Singleton] attribute from the function entrypoint methods. (I didn't even realize they were there. It's amazing what you'll notice after a good nights sleep!)

EDIT: The attribute was added a long time ago and was no longer necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The "Singleton lock acquired" is a policy for Function [reliable event processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reliable-event-processing). Here is a description with queue triggered function might help you to understand.

> With queues, reliable messaging comes naturally. When paired with a
> Functions trigger, the function creates a lock on the queue message.
> If processing fails, the lock is released to allow another instance to
> retry processing. Processing then continues until either the message
> is evaluated successfully, or it is added to a poison queue.

Comment: depending on how many messages you receive and how fast you need to process them, you could try to limit the scale out to only 1 Function instance with WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT=1 https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-functions-limiting-throughput-and-scalability-of-a-serverless-app-5b1c381491e3
This might help with the locking issue